# Create column and use as join key inside of JOIN in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to create a column to use as the join key inside of the join like:

```
df1.join(df2
        .withColumn('NewDF2Column', SOME_OPERATION)),
        df1['key'] = df2['NewDF2Column'], how = 'left'))
```

PySpark can never find the NewDF2Column to use as the join key. It works if I create it first in another dataframe, but not dynamically like this. Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes are immutable, which means that you need to reassign everytime your variable to get the result from it. In this case, you are creating your `NewDF2Column` on the first parameter of `join` operation, but the second parameter where you references `NewDF2Column` again can't see the changes made before. How to solve it?

##### First option

```py
# Creating before joining
df2 = df2.withColumn('NewDF2Column', SOME_OPERATION)

output_df = df1.join(df2, df1['key'] = df2['NewDF2Column'], how='left')
```

##### Second option

```
# Creating a column to join with the same name as df1
output_df = df1.join(df2.withColumn('key', SOME_OPERATION), on='key', how='left')
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I have multiple join columns. Both options work great if I join on on key, but as soon as I try adding additional columns i.e.  (df1['key'] =  df2['key']) & (df1['keyB'] =  df2['keyB']), it still can't find 'key'. Any thoughts on multi key joins under the same scenario?

Comment: For sure, you must pass an array of strings, like `df1.join(df2, on=['key', 'keyB'], how='left')`